# Stop-gradient operator in VQ-VAE

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, gradient-descent

In the vector-quantized variational autoencoder (VQ-VAE), the objective function (Eq. (3) [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00937v2))  contains

$$\left\lVert \mathrm{sg}[z_e(x)] - e \right\rVert^2 + \left\lVert z_e(x) - \mathrm{sg}[e] \right\rVert^2,$$
where $\mathrm{sg}$ is the stop-gradient operator.

(Note: The second term can have a weighting factor $\beta$, but "the results did not vary for values of $β$ ranging from $0.1$ to $2.0$. We use $β = 0.25$", so let's assume $\beta=1$.)

What are the advantages of this objective over directly optimizing
$$\left\lVert z_e(x) - e \right\rVert^2$$
instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking for the same question. I have finally deduced the following. I think it is a learning factor that balance the importance between terms (codebook loss and commitment loss).

If the Beta factor is smaller than 1, it means that the encoder is updated more faster than the codebook.

That is interesting for example if we think about it from a centroid perspective (codebook), we do not want them to update strongly in each iteration because we have to preserve some information of the previous batches (and more important if the batch is small).

In short, we want the centroids (codebook) to move slowly and the encoder samples can be updated faster. Probably this technique can minimize the noise produced by the mini-batch sampling in contrast than use all the dataset.

This is what I have deduced, if it is not correct please someone indicate it.

Comment: So is VQ-VAE equivalent to choosing different learning rates for different trainable parameters? (Like setting `lambda` from the so-called *gradient reversal layer* to `-beta` instead of to `1`?)

Comment: Yes, exactly in the gradient reversal layer, that lambda regularizes the implication it has, it would be the same concept. Basically, to control the update weight in the codebook and encoder. Without the sg operator, this could not be done because both terms would have the same update weight.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I guess setting `beta=1` has the same effect as not using `sg`. It's interesting that they actually don't need `sg` for their dataset (they use a `beta` value that yields similar results to `beta=1`), yet they (implicitly) let the reader know that a serious use of `sg` (by setting a very different `beta` value) might be beneficial in other cases.

Answer (score -1):

If you take gradients, the two formulas you mentioned are the same.

However, if we write in the form of the first formula, fix $z_e$ (zero gradient), let $e$ approach $z_e$ and inversely.

I think it would be easier for training.

Comment: Is it easier for training just empirically without understanding why (in that case where do such ideas come from?), or is there some understanding why this is easier for training?